# Why does printing to a utf-8 file fail?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, lxml

So I ran into a problem this afternoon, I was able to solve it, but I don't quite understand why it worked.

this is related to a problem I had the other week: [python check if utf-8 string is uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391442/python-check-if-utf-8-string-is-uppercase)

basically, the following will not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import codecs
from lxml import etree

outFile = codecs.open('test.xml', 'w', 'utf-8') #cannot use codecs.open()

root = etree.Element('root')
sect = etree.SubElement(root,'sect')


words = (   u'\u041c\u041e\u0421\u041a\u0412\u0410', # capital of Russia, all uppercase
            u'R\xc9SUM\xc9',    # RESUME with accents
            u'R\xe9sum\xe9',    # Resume with accents
            u'R\xe9SUM\xe9', )  # ReSUMe with accents

for word in words:
    print word
    if word.encode('utf8').decode('utf8').isupper(): #.isupper won't function on utf8 
        title = etree.SubElement(sect,'title')
        title.text = word
    else:
       item = etree.SubElement(sect,'item')
       item.text = word 

print>>outFile,etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8')
```

it fails with the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./temp.py", line 25, in 
>       print >>outFile,etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8')
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py",
>   line 691, in write
>       return self.writer.write(data)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py",
>   line 351, in write
>       data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 66:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

but if I open the new file without `codecs.open('test.xml', 'w', 'utf-8')` and instead use 
`outFile = open('test.xml', 'w')` it works perfectly.

**So whats happening??**

- since `encoding='utf-8'` is specified in `etree.tostring()` is it encoding the file again?
- if I leave `codecs.open()` and remove `encoding='utf-8'` the file then becomes an ascii file. Why? becuase `etree.tostring()` has a default encoding of ascii I persume?
- but `etree.tostring()` is simply being written to stdout, and is then redirect to a file that was created as a utf-8 file??

  - is `print>>` not workings as I expect? `outFile.write(etree.tostring())` behaves the same way.

Basically, why wouldn't this work? what is going on here. It might be trivial, but I am obviously a bit confused and have a desire to figure out why my solution works,

Comment: It looks like tostring() produces a string, and writing to the file opened with codec.open expects unicode. Try using plain `open()` to open the file, and leaving the encoding='utf-8' parameter when you call tostring(). Also, `word.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')`!?

Comment: @Thomas K, 1. I am okay with using  `open()`, just curious as to why. 2. `word.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')` must be intreperted wrong. I ensure you I need to use word.decode('utf8') in my project which has its words feeded to it from a different file. see this for more on .isupper() with utf8 => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391442/python-check-if-utf-8-string-is-uppercase

Comment: your call to tostring() produces an encoded string (not unicode). The file opened with codecs.open() expects to receive unicode, so when you give it a bytestring, it chokes (in fact, it tries to decode as ascii and re-encode as utf-8). 2: I understand that you may have needed to decode, but you're encoding and then immediately decoding with the same codec, which gives you back what you started with. I highly recommend reading this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @matchew: You might want to take a look at [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368805/python-unicodedecodeerror-am-i-misunderstanding-encode/370199#370199) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've opened the file with UTF-8 encoding, which means that it expects Unicode strings.

tostring is encoding to UTF-8 (in the form of bytestrings, str), which you're writing to the file.

Because the file is expecting Unicode, it's decoding the bytestrings to Unicode using the default ASCII encoding so that it can then encode the Unicode to UTF-8.

Unfortunately, the bytestrings aren't ASCII.

EDIT: The best advice to avoid this kind of problem is to use Unicode internally, decoding on input and encoding on output.

Comment: Now that I've stepped back from this problem, your answer seems to make the most sense. Too bad Thomas K did answer with it, as he had basically said the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `print>>outFile` is a little strange.  I don't have `lxml` installed, but the built-in `xml.etree` library is similar (but doesn't support `pretty_print`).  Wrap the `root` Element in an ElementTree and use the write method.

Also, if you using a `# coding` line to declare the encoding of the source file, you can use readable Unicode strings instead of escape codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8

import codecs
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

root = etree.Element(u'root')
sect = etree.SubElement(root,u'sect')


words = [u'МОСКВА',u'RÉSUMÉ',u'Résumé',u'RéSUMé']

for word in words:
    print word
    if word.isupper():
        title = etree.SubElement(sect,u'title')
        title.text = word
    else:
       item = etree.SubElement(sect,u'item')
       item.text = word 

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('text.xml',xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I quite like `print>>outFile`, but I agree in that it isn't very pythonic. Overall, this post hasn't told me anything I really didn't know. Thanks for giving it a shot though.

Comment: @Mark Tolenen: He copied the data with "escape codes" from an answer I wrote to one of his previous questions. The purpose of using "escape codes" (the output of repr()) was to reduce the ambiguity that was floating around ... One needs very good eyes to distinguish between u'MOCKBA' (Latin) and u'МОСКВА' (Cyrillic). Crappy answers to his previous problem would work with the Latin and fail with the Cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MRABs answer some lines of code:

```
import codecs
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('root')
sect = etree.SubElement(root,'sect')

# do some other xml building here

with codecs.open('test.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(root, encoding=unicode))
```